# How can I disable showing files and unstyled index page in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Okay here's my problem:

My website:
https://www.bffmatch.com/

If I go to a subdirectory that is in my website root it shows index page without any css which is very weird:
https://www.bffmatch.com/css/

And if i go to a file it shows that file:
https://www.bffmatch.com/css/match.css

The same goes for php files and whatnot

So how can i disable access to these and just redirect to my website root or something

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homepage.css">
```

`css/homepage.css` is a relative path.

The browser uses the URL of the current page to make a full URL out of it.

The URL of the current page is`https://www.bffmatch.com/css/`. This makes `css/homepage.css` to be expanded `https://www.bffmatch.com/css/css/homepage.css` and it does not exist.

Use full paths for the resources and it will work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/homepage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/profile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/match.css">
```

And so on.

Use your browser's Web Developer Tools to find out other requests that cannot be found (the server's response for them is `404 Not Found`).

Comment: Thanks! That was a dumb oversight on my part to use relative file paths. Is there any way to prevent users from viewing files in browser?